# Proving $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + |x|^{k}}$ converges if and only if $|x| > 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to show

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 + |x|^{k}} $$

converges if and only if $|x| > 1$. I think that the best way to show the backwards direction is to assume we havve $|x| \leq 1$ then maybe doing the integral test? But I didn't get anywhere with this.  I don't relaly have an idea of how to do it with the other direction either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $|x|>1$
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+|x|^{k}}{1+|x|^{k+1}}
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{|x|^{-k}+1}{|x|^{-k}+|x|}=\frac{1}{|x|}<1.
$$
Now apply the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

For $|x|\leqslant 1$, 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+|x|^{k}}
\neq0.
$$

Comment: @joseph: "first assume it converges, then show it requires $|x|>1$" is **equivalent** to "assume that $|x|\leqslant1$, and show it diverges".